# Как удалить часть текса и url

Tags: php, wordpress

Использую плагин для wordpress - qtranslate x. Вроде все норм, но при переходе с одного языка на другой редиректит на главную страницу.
Это из-за того, что жостко прописана ссылка в переключателе. 
Для русского языка - `<a href="site.ru/ru" title="Русский (ru)">ru</a>`
И для английского языка - `<a href="site.ru/en" title="Английский(en)">en</a>`
Меня это не устраивает. Я хочу сделать все без редиректа на главную. 
Нашел в нете функцию для wordpress которая возвращает путь после url `<?php echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] ?>.` Но она возвращает его уже с префиксом языка.
Тоесть я сделал `<a href="<?php echo "/ru".$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] ?>" title="Русский (ru)">ru</a>`
И оно мне возвращает `site.ru/ru/ru`. 
Вообщем как мне из `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` удалить префикс языка. Я в PHP не силен. Примерно представляю, что нужно запихнуть ее в переменную удалить там префикс и вывести. Но как это конкретно сделать не знаю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$rest = substr("site.ru/ru/ru", 0, -3);
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!